# Facebook Like Buttons inside Facebook Apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, href, facebook-apps, facebook-social-plugins

If you have a Facebook App, such as a simple page promoting something, can you still install a Facebook Like button inside the app/view itself.

The reason I'm asking is that it *is* working for me, but if I try to specify the URL of the Like button to the URL of my app, then the button doesn't display at all. If I put a different URL in, then it works fine.

For example, the link to a developer page, will work fine:

```
data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Uktv-developer-area/123456789000000"
```

But, if I include the reference to the app, it breaks:

```
data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Uktv-developer-area/123456789000000?sk=app_123456789000000"
```

Can anyone spot why this is happening?